# Spring JPA One To Many Hibernate Insert Data With An Existing Entity

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to insert an entity to a database but this entity has a one to many relationship and one of the entity already exits on the database. For instance let's think **Course** and **Instructor**, when you create Course with an existing Instructor I have *Status 500 error*.

My codes are as follows:

- I am using [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) annotations so instead of constractions, getters and setters for less boilerplate code.

### Course

```java
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Course {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String course_name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}  )
    @JoinColumn(name = "instructor_fk", nullable = false)
    private Instructor instructor;
}
```

### Instructor

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "instructor")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Instructor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String instructor_name;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "instructor",
            cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}
    )
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Course> courses;
}
```

### CRUD Repository

```java
@Repository
public interface CourseRepository extends CrudRepository<Course, Integer> {

}
```

### DataSource

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CourseDataSource {
    private @NotEmpty
    @JsonProperty("course_name")
    String courseName;
    private @NotEmpty
    @JsonProperty("instructor_name")
    String instructorName;
}
```

### Service

```java
@Service
public class CompartmentService {
    @Autowired
    private CouseRepository courseRepository;

    public Course createCourse(CourseDataSource coursetDataSource) {

        Instructor instructor = new Instructor();
        instructor.setinstructorName(coursetDataSource.getInstructorName());


        Course course = new Course();

        course.setCourseName(coursetDataSource.getCourseName());

        course.setInstructor(instructor);

        return courseRepository.save(course);


    }
```

**But I am getting this Error when I have a Post request with existing *Instructor*:**

```
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [instructor_pkey]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement",
```

Comment: Where do you set `instructor` to the `course`? Is this line correct `course.setRateCalculations(instructor);` And please post the `course` class as well. Or is it the `Author` class

Comment: Sorry **Author** should be **Course**, *course.setRateCalculations(instructor);* should be *course.setInstructor(instructor);*

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new `Instructor` you need to refer to the existing one

```
public Course createCourse(CourseDataSource coursetDataSource) {
    Instructor instructor = entityManager.createQuery("FROM Instructor i where i.instructor_name = :name", Instructor.class).setParameter("name", coursetDataSource.getInstructorName()).getSingleResult();

    Course course = new Course();
    course.setCourseName(coursetDataSource.getCourseName());
    course.setInstructor(instructor);
    return courseRepository.save(course);
}
```

Comment: I think this is in right direction but .getReference() expect an ID for second parameter not a string?